# How do i avoid sub report in this situation

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, subreport

I have to bring data from 3 tables. If i create a JOIN query, this is how the data looks like:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7bc5e/1

I want to create SSRS report but i do not want to create sub report. This is how i need my SSRS report to look like:

```
OrderId Title Notes
                  DetailId ItemId Quantity UnitPrice
                                                    ItemName Color Size
```

Can i create the above layout in the SSRS report without using 2 sub-reports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use groups: http://sql-bi-dev.blogspot.com/2010/09/groups-in-ssrs-2008.html

Let me know if there is something that I am missing.